# PDFNet filling the signature fields

Tags: java, pdftron, pdfnet

I try to use PDFNetAndroid to filling signature fields and i saw some examples that sign these fields by code(not by human).
e.g http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/samplecode/DigitalSignaturesTest.java.html

I want in the moment that the client touching the mobile screen on signature field it's opening with window or something and the client drawing on the filed.

Someone know how to do that?

**UPDATE:** I have pdf file with signature field that i was created by acrobat.
I want to sign on the field in my android device.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooxd6.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Can someone explain why the negative score?
I just ask simple question, i gave examples and it's very clearly

Comment: The second paragraph is not clear. Can you elaborate on what you are asking. Perhaps you could provide a screen shot.

Comment: @Ryan I update my question

Answer (score 0):

PDFNet Android SDK already includes, out of the box, the ability to click on a Signature field and using touch events, draw a signature.

Please download the SDK, run the CompleteReader sample project, and open the getting_started.pdf. Then navigate to page 8 and tap the signature field.

The code/logic for handling this is in the PDFViewCtrlTools project, in particular the `lib\src\PDFViewCtrlTools\src\com\pdftron\pdf\tools\DigitalSignature.java` file in the SDK. All tools code is provided in the SDK so you can customize to your business needs.

Note, that we also have a show case app, called [Xodo](https://www.xodo.com/), avaiable for free in all mobile stores. This app uses CompleteReader as its foundation.

Comment: In the jar file PDFNet.jar the packet tools didn't exist.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean exactly by "packet tools didn't exist"? PDFNet.jar is just an interface to one of the PDFNet.so files for the targeted architecture. Tools code is generated into a different jar.

Comment: "Tools code is generated into a different jar" where this jar?

Comment: The tools come pre-built in `lib/PDFViewCtrlTools.aar`.
See Parts A and B in the section "Adding support for Annotations, Text Selection and Form Filling" here https://blog.pdftron.com/2017/03/21/getting-started-with-android-2/ for more information.

Comment: I followed with part A and B.
When I followed A I get this message: "Error:(15, 0) Could not find any public constructor for class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet_Decorated which accepts parameters [java.lang.String, org.gradle.api.internal.file.BaseDirFileResolver].

When I followed B I get error message that missing files.

Comment: Seems like a new issue, separate from this SO question. I would recommend sending your project to PDFTron support for more assistance.